# Windows 8 PC added to trusted list but still thinks it's untrusted

Tags: windows-8, operating-systems, windows-live

I just upgraded both my PCs to Windows 8 x64 and I went through the process to add my PCs to the trusted list on Windows Live.  Both computers appear on the list in my account settings online, but neither one seems to realize that is the case.

I keep getting messages from action center to "Trust this PC" and I can't sync passwords or any other trusted PC only features.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Upgraded from windows 7 or clean install ?

Comment: Upgraded from windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my problem was I hadn't installed all of the most recent implementations of the Windows Live suite.  I upgraded to the Windows 8 version of Windows Live Essentials and after a couple restarts it started to recognize my PC.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some links that may give you some steps to try. I'm not sure, from reading your original post whether or not you received a verification code via SMS or email. If you haven't done that step, that is the first point of order. I just dug around in the Win 8 forums at MS and pulled these links out. If none of this works, please let us know... I'm sure someone will be able to help with just a bit more information...

[Windows 8 'Trust this PC' issue](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/answers?tId=75578e4c-7d5a-49d8-8bd4-30d62fb9cb16)  
[What is a trusted PC?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/what-is-trusted-pc)

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep Windows Live Essentials program running to get a Trusted PC.
another post i found said

Internet Explorer 10 will open you to the Microsoft Account Settings page. Enter in the code that Microsoft sends via text to your smartphone or via email.(During this process ie must be executed with admin privileges to work perfect !!!)

Hope it works !!!

Comment: can you please give the link to "another post i found"

Answer (score 0):

Since you have upgraded your PC with a new operating system, it had been detedted as a new PC.
With the new system update, you can remove old inaccessible security information on your account automatically after 30 days. To do that:

1. Log in to this [link](https://account.live.com/proofs/Manage).
2. Click Delete on the security information you do not have access to. (Alternate email, Trusted PC, Mobile number)
3. Select  "No, I Don't have access" button. (The date on when the security information will be removed will appear )
4. Click Delete Security Info.
5. Update the account with new Security Info.
6. Click Save.

You just need to wait for 30 days for all the information to be removed and the new security information to be automatically confirmed.
Try this workaround in adding the new PC:
Hit Windows Icon on your computer +R.
Type wlstartup.exe and click Ok.
It will lauch Windows Live Essentials 2011.
Log in and select  Make this my Trusted PC.
Thanks!

Comment: i think main culprit is the previous os security info that does not allow you to complete process successfully.